# How to configure `hg push` to push to current branch only?

Tags: mercurial

I would like to configure Mercurial to push the commits on the current branch only, instead of all draft commits - much like Git does when the `push.default` is set to `simple`. I scanned the `hgrc` manual page, but couldn't locate the option which enforces this. How is it called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although deprecated, you can set defaults for commands in `hgrc`:

```
[defaults]
push = -r .
```

The recommended alternative is aliases:

```
[alias]
pushcurrent = push -r .
```